# how to add file chooser to swing GUI form Palette components IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea, components, palette

I already developed an application that train some text files in order to creat a data model which i will use in another class to identify the language of the document.
For now i have written and finished writing two classes one for Training the data models and the other to identify any given document language.
I wrote the code that i can get the file paths as arguments to my main method in order for the user to pass the file names as arguments to my main method.
But now i decided to create a simple GUI form for the application and i need the file chooser But when i choose the GUI form i could not find the file chooser from all the Swing palette components available.
How can i add it?
Note: i am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.0 Ultimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File chooser is something that usually pops up based on some button click.
So, what can you do is, inside button listener make an object JFileChooser and play with that.

```
fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.showOpenDialog(parentPanel);
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it